# How to interpret the "もの" in どうしたものでしょうか

Tags: meaning

I would like to ask how to interpret the "もの" or "もん" in the phrase "どうしたものでしょうか" or "どうしたもんか". Does it have any specific meaning or serve a grammatical function? I know the phrases have the same meaning as "どうすればいい?", but I am curious about this もの, though.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28797/9831

Answer (score 3):

ものだ after a verb has several special functions, and one of them is to describe an advice based on common sense.

- [Difference between sentence final ものだ and ことだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6372/5010)
- [The meanings of ものだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/5010)

So どうしたものでしょうか is like どうするべきでしょうか. Basically it's seeking for what an ordinary person would do in a similar situation. That said, どうしたものか/どうしたものでしょうか has been established as a set phrase said when someone is at a loss, and you may not have to take it as a genuine question and answer it.