# ~乙女ならばともかく: Translation and grammar issue

Tags: grammar, translation, conditionals

I was reading *The Tatami Galaxy*, and I came across the following sentence:
**うら若き乙女ならばともかく**、二十歳過ぎたむさ苦しい男を誰が抱きしめてやりたいものか。[pg.295]
I know ~ともかく means "leaving aside", "never mind X,..." But I'm having trouble making sense of it in this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

There's certainly something to be said for writting down your ideas. half way through wrriting my question the lightbulb came on!

Since I didn't find anything on ~ならばともかく on the exchange, I figured I would post my answer for the use of the community.

First things first, this　~ならばともかく　is equivalent to ～ならともかく (much in the same way ならば・なら　are the same thing). I guess it has more of the archaic/high-flown flavor "watakushi" (the main character of the Tatami Galaxy) is known for.
Now, this ~ならともかく is a bit different from regular old ~ともかく. It also makes a contrast, but in the following way :

**Noun1**ならともかく、**Noun2** + Verb

*While **Noun1** might be/do/go (for)/etc, **Noun2** + Verb*

[1](https://takoboto.jp/bunpo/1554) Verb is in the negative (for what I've seen)

[2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97293/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B) Verb determines the meaning of both parts of the sentence.

This is a bit abstract, so let's parse the passage in the question to gorund it:

**うら若き乙女ならばともかく、二十歳過ぎたむさ苦しい男を誰が抱きしめてやりたいものか**

So, the verb here is 抱きしめる　[to hug]. The negative sense is given by the construction [～ものか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97293/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B). The verb applies to both, parts of the sentence (what's before and after ~ならばともかく）, with the idea that it applies to the former, but not the latter. Finally, we get:

*While it might be possible to embrace a fresh, young maiden, who could ever want to embrace a filthy twentysomething?!*

Notes:

1. The thing that threw me off, is that in this case what's being opposed is the **object** of the verb, not the **Subject** . I'm not 100% sure of this, but the alternative reading seems a bit contradictory (*"While a fresh young maiden might want to, who [else?] could ever want to embrace a filthy twentysomething"*). If I'm wrong here, I'd love to know why.
2. For more examples (and a a more concise explanation) look [here](https://takoboto.jp/bunpo/1554)